# When a Stinking Cloud is moved onto a creature, does the creature take damage immediately?

Tags: dnd-4e, spells, wizard, zone

In a recent session of D&D 4e, a **Stinking Cloud** was moved onto a creature who was outside of it.

Stinking Cloud Effect:

> ...Creatures that enter the zone or
>   start their turns there take 1d10 +
>   Intelligence modifier poison damage..

If a wizard moves the stinking cloud onto a monster during the wizard's turn, does that count as the creature "entering" the stinking cloud and thus forcing the monster to take immediate damage?

Comment: In general 4e is rules as written (i.e. powers only do what they implicitly say they do).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**No**

There's nothing that says they take damage when the cloud enters THEIR square, and doing so would double the amount of damage the cloud does to the creature that round.

Answer (score 4):

**No**

Reading the text literally says that the creature does not. It did not enter and it did not start its turn there.

For the role-playing aspect of the game, if the creature decides to move out of the cloud on its turn I'd explain that as the cloud is moving, the creature moves away from the cloud.

Comment: Agreed, except that the creature couldn't move out of the cloud until the beginning of its next turn..so that would mean it started its turn in the cloud and it would then take damage as described in the spell description.